# How to load Gensim FastText model in native FastText

Tags: gensim, fasttext

I trained a FastText model in Gensim. I want to use it to encode my sentences. Specifically, I want to use this feature from native FastText:

```
./fasttext print-word-vectors model.bin < queries.txt
```

How to I save the model in Gensim so that it is the correct binary format that can be understood by native FastText?

I am using FastText 0.1.0 and Gensim 3.4.0 under Python 3.4.3.

In essence, I need the inverse of the load_binary_data() as given in the [Gensim FastText doc](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html).

Answer (score 0):

You probably wont find such a functionality in gensim as that would mean dependence on the internal structure and code like what you see in fasttext-python (which uses [pybind](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/intro.html) to directly call the internal fasttext api). To have such a huge dependency on an external library is something which the creators of gensim would like to avoid and that is why they probably [deprecated the functionality to call the fasttext wrapper](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/fasttext.html). RIght now gensim only seeks to provide fasttext algorithm through its own internal implementation. I would suggest you use the [python bindings for fasttext](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ pip install .
```

Now run the training set in your python application with the fasttext model.

```
from fastText import train_unsupervised
model = train_unsupervised(input="pathtotextfile", model='skipgram')
model.save_model('model.bin')
```

This would save the model in the fastText command line format. So you should now be able to run the following.

```
$ ./fasttext print-word-vectors model.bin < queries.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I was hoping NOT to have to retrain the model that I have already trained in gensim.